# How to emit "LIMIT 1" in SQL select with QuerydslPredicateExecutor::findOne()?

Tags: spring-boot, querydsl

In my simple Spring boot application (Spring Web Starter 2.1.7, Spring Data JPA 2.1.7, h2 1.4.199, querydsl-jpa 4.2.1, p6spy-spring-boot-starter 1.5.6)
I call `QuerydslPredicateExecutor::findOne()` method to fetch one record from database. But log shows it queries database without `"LIMIT 1"` clause:

```
public interface AbonRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Abon, Integer>, QuerydslPredicateExecutor<Abon> {
}

@RestController
public class AbonentsController {

    @Autowired
    private AbonRepository repo;

    @GetMapping
    public Iterable<Abon> txget(@QuerydslPredicate(root = Abon.class) Predicate predicate) {
        ...
        transactionTemplate.execute(new TransactionCallbackWithoutResult() { // BEGIN transacion
            ...
            Abon abon = repo.findOne(predicate).orElse(null);
            ...
```

Log:

```
...
2019-09-08 17:32:05.125 DEBUG 10588 --- [.1-33133-exec-3] o.h.e.t.internal.TransactionImpl         : On TransactionImpl creation, JpaCompliance#isJpaTransactionComplianceEnabled == false
2019-09-08 17:32:05.125 DEBUG 10588 --- [.1-33133-exec-3] o.h.e.t.internal.TransactionImpl         : begin
2019-09-08 17:32:13.190  INFO 10588 --- [.1-33133-exec-3] p6spy                                    : #1567953133190 | took 0ms | statement | connection 7| url jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
select abon0_.id as id1_0_, abon0_.edit_lock_id as edit_loc4_0_, abon0_.licevoj_kod as licevoj_2_0_, abon0_.street_id as street_i3_0_ from abon abon0_ where abon0_.street_id=?
select abon0_.id as id1_0_, abon0_.edit_lock_id as edit_loc4_0_, abon0_.licevoj_kod as licevoj_2_0_, abon0_.street_id as street_i3_0_ from abon abon0_ where abon0_.street_id=1;
...
```

What should be configured so this call will append `"LIMIT 1"` to SQL query?

P.S.: Tried this call with Eclipselink 2.7.4 - no `"LIMIT 1"` also.

P.P.S: Answers with `repo.findAll(predicate,PageRequest.of(0, 1));` aren't acceptable as it emits unneeded count query.

P.P.P.S: Currently I copied `QuerydslJpaPredicateExecutor` and 4 its friends (`CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor`, `DefaultQueryHints`, `JpaRepositoryFactory`, `QueryHints`) from `org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support` package to my project and patched `findOne()` implementation with `.limit(1)`. But this way looks quite like as monkey-patching. Also this emits `"LIMIT 1 OFFSET 0"` instead of just `"LIMIT 1"` (well this isn't too annoying).

---

Links:

- [Spring Data JPA - Querydsl Web Support](https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/spring-framework/spring-data/query-dsl-web-support.html) (www.logicbig.com)
- [REST Query Language with Querydsl Web Support](https://www.baeldung.com/rest-api-search-querydsl-web-in-spring-data-jpa) (www.baeldung.com)

Note: The 2nd article is the latest one in its series. Click on the `"This article is part of a series"` div just before "1. Overview" to get
the whole list of articles about how to implement your query language with JPA Criteries or with JPA Specifications or with Querydsl.

Comment: why not user native query in repository?

Comment: @SurajKumarAgrahari its too simple ;) And there are too many other things I have to do right now instead of coding my own query language implementation. Check links appended to the question.